# Prove or disprove that the quotient of two evens, if it is an integer, is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Can you disprove something with simply a counterexample?
Just like:

$\frac 62=3$

Disproved?

Comment: yes, it only ever takes one counterexample.

Comment: ok thanks @mdave16

Comment: @Bucephalus Or even $2 / 2 = 1\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's exactly how you disprove something (that begins with "for all").

Comment: Ok, thanks @SahibaArora

Comment: ... something *that begins with "for all"*.